# Prove that $(h_1 \times h_2)(f) $ = $h_1(f) \circ h_2(f)$ .

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

We have linear map from $R[x]\to End(V)$ ($R[x]-polynomials$)

For elements in $End(V)$ we have composition. I am reading notes and it says that
we have
$(h_1 \times h_2)(f) $ = $h_1(f) \circ h_2(f)$ and if you want to derive you can easily derive it from $f_1 \circ(f_2+f_3)=(f_1\circ f_2)+(f_1\circ f_3)$

$h_1,h_2\in R[x]$
$f_1,f_2,f_3\in End(V)$

We have $\beta_f$ linear map from polynomial of real numbers to $EndV$.$h_1,h_2 \in R[x]$,$f_1,f_2,f_3 \in End(V)$.
$\times$ denotes multiplication of polynomials.

I tried but couldn't prove it.Can you help how we can prove it?

Comment: If something from my post is unclear please say I will change it.

Comment: What sort of thing is $R$? What sort of thing is $V$? What are the scalars when you say "linear map"? What exactly are you trying to prove?